# linux how to get GUI-application like win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")?

Tags: linux, user-interface, winapi, com

win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell"), is that possible in linux environment, python cat get certain app, like win32com

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. There's no COM in Linux. If there were there still isn't Windows' Shell in Linux.

Comment: so, how can I active running gui-application thru python-shell cmd?

Comment: I don't know what that is supposed to mean. I answered the question that was asked. If you have a new question you can hit the "Ask Question" button.